# WPF MVVM Timeline

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, styles, timeline

I want something like this:

[Example Timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drkHt.jpg)

But I don't really know how to realise this.

I want to show movies in this timeline. The timeline should show my movielist with the date I added them.

My ideas:

1. A `Listbox` with a binding to my `list<T>` movielist, `styling`. The `Listbox` like the picture shows. But how? Some style ideas? I am new to styling.
2. `Grid` with 3 columns, Stackpanel in rows 0 and 2 (row 1 as placeholder), every stackpanel loads a half movielist and shows his movies like movie, placeholder, movie. But makes this sense?

Every movie has properties to use

- `Picture`
- `Name`
- `Rating`
- `UserAddDate`

It is hard to describe what I want, so feel free to ask.

Comment: I assume the groups will be summarized , i.e. "2 weeks ago" will have multiple entries and not 3x "2 weeks ago" inside it. This you can only solve by creating your own  user control that does this kind of stuff. There is no out-of-box solution, at least not in WPF. Maybe third-party libraries

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right general idea of how to create something like that. A `listview` of your movies and a `grid` would be a good layout.

You will definitely need to look into styling to create something as professional looking at what you described.  [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18388/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-Styles) should get you started in the right direction.

[This](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/1e050f/grid-layout-in-wpf/) should help you with getting started on your layout.